# Tensorflow: Best way of creating training data with float as label

Tags: image, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow version 2.4.0-dev20201009 in python 3.7.
My dataset are in the subfolder "data\Images". The label of an image is a float number between 1 and 5 and can read from the allTestData.csv from the subfolder "data".

What is the best way to read the data with validation split of 30 percent? So far I wanted to use
*tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory* but this doesn't help me to incorperate the labels correctly, as all my images are in one folder and do not have one-hot encoded vectors as labels. How would you do this in tensorflow?

For the sake of completeness, I planed to use

```
def create_model():
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False))
  model.trainable = True
  model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
  model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu"))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.losses.mean_squared_error,
                metrics=[tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

  model.summary()
  return model
```

for training the model. The question is only regarding how to read the training data?

Comment: have you taken a look at `flow_from_dataframe`?

Comment: I looked it up, it doesnt look like that you can write something like "label = float". Maybe I should simply write a function which reads the label as a float number

Comment: You can always use `tf.cast` function to convert tensor's dtype. I recommend using `tf.data.Dataset` for dataset loading.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.
The best way was to write a manual function that reads the labels and images.
Assume that the images are in 'data\Images' and the labels are in a .txt file and the labels are in a .txt file at 'data\train_test_files\All_labels.txt'. Then the following two methods will do the job:

```
def loadImages(IMG_SIZE):
  path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data\\Images')
  training_data=[]
  labelMap = getLabelMap()
  for img in os.listdir(path):
    out_array = np.zeros((350,350, 3), np.float32) #350x350 is the pixel size of the images
    try:
     img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
     img_array=img_array.astype('float32')
     out_array = cv2.normalize(img_array, out_array, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
     out_array = cv2.resize(out_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)
     training_data.append([out_array, float(labelMap[img])])
    except Exception as e:
      pass
 return training_data

 def getLabelMap():
   map = {}
   path = os.getcwd()
   path = os.path.join(path, "data\\train_test_files\\All_labels.txt")
   f = open(path, "r")
   for line in f:
     line = line.split()     #lines in txt file are of the form 'image_name.jpg 3.2'
     map[line[0]] = line[1]  #3.2 is the label
   f.close()
   return map
#call of method:
training_set=[]
training_set = loadImages(244)  #I want to have my images resized to 244x244
```

Comment: don't use map as variable name, it is a builtin function.  I suggest `label_map` instead.